# Is it bad to use scooter oil in a motorcycle?

Tags: motorcycle, oil, oil-change, cagiva

I am supposed to change the oil
(Transmission) of my 2004 Cagiva Raptor 125.
The recommended oil by the manufacter is Agip racing 5w40.
I bought Motul Scooter Power 5w40, which is more expensive and is supposed to work for maxi scooters up to 650cc (a lot more than my bike's 125cc).
Is this a bad idea? They have the same viscosity so i figure it would be ok. However, i want to hear other people's opinion.

Comment: Zou should check out the oil's specific characteristics ie the standards both oils are manufactured to API ratings etc and that will tell you if they are equivalent.